# Can i set a class like class = 8

Tags: java, types

I apologize for the badly worded title, but i cannot find a better way to describe my question.

I'm making a custom Degree class that will only hold any number between 0 and 360, any additions higher will be resolved down to their 0-360 equivalent. I was wondering if it was possible to do what primitive types do I.e Int a = 1.

I doubt this is possible, but if it is, how can i do it?

Comment: `Int` is not a type in java. There is only a class `Integer` and a primitive type `int`. Java is case-sensitive :)

Comment: No, this is not possible in java, because auto boxing only applies to the built-in numeric types and there are no implicit constructors.

Comment: @Dave - Of course it's possible. They'll just have to make their own wrapper class.

Comment: And yes, you can create many setter methods which receive different arguments. `public void set(Integer a)` | `public void set(Double a)`. It is called `function overloading`.

Comment: you can not make assignment of any built in types to your class. because internally built in types in java have corresponding wrapper classes and automatically built in types will be assigned using wrapper class ie Integer x=8; but we cant do the same for our own class. to do so we can use some reflection concept but have to work around on this,but not possible directly.

Comment: Okay thanks. get and set it is.

Comment: @Rudi as far as I'm aware, there is no way in java to make the line `Degree deg = 1;` compile, which is what I understand this question to be.

Comment: @Dave - It's unfortunate that `extends Number` doesn't offer some way of defining autoboxing behaviour. The Java 5 specs say that autoboxing can only occur with the pre-defined wrapper classes.

Comment: @Dave yes this is pretty much what i was asking. Rudi Yes i have looked into this having read the term, its a shame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you described would look like in Java. You will have to create a wrapper class which represents your degrees. Internally however, we will just be using an `Integer` object (or `int` primitive would work fine).

```
public class Degree {

    private Integer degrees;

    // Constructor, takes an Integer object or int primitive
    public Degree(Integer deg){
        setDegrees(deg);
    }
    // Get degrees from your wrapper object
    public Integer getDegrees(){
        return degrees;
    }
    // Set degress of your wrapper object
    public void setDegrees(Integer deg){
        if(deg<361 && deg>-1){ degrees = deg; }
        else if(deg>360){ degrees = 360; }
        else if(deg<0){ degrees = 0; }
    }
}
```

To use this in code somewhere else you would just use;

```
Degree d = new Degree(31);
```

You will probably want to [override the `toString();` method](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) as well as the `equals();` method, for ease of using your new `Degree` class. I hope this helps.

---

**Edit:** The behaviour where you declare a class and use the `=` operator to declare it a primitive is called autoboxing. A behaviour that has been possible since Java 5, but only works with a pre-set list of wrapper classes defined in the [Java 5 specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).

That list includes `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float`, `Double`.

Comment: I would suggest a factory method rather than a constructor, like the number types' `valueOf`. That leaves you free to have cached values, like 0, 90, etc. or cache-as-created. Of course, your class would need to be immutable, but that's good practice anyway.

Comment: You have doulbe code, in your constructor you could call setDegrees(deg); and remove the double code.

Answer (score 1):

I decided i would post my finished class here in case anyone wanted it for reference.

```
public class Degree extends Number implements Comparable<Degree>{

    float degreeFloat;

    public Degree(){
        degreeFloat = 0;
    }

    public Degree(float degrees){
        this.set(degrees);
    }

    public Degree(int degrees){
        this.set(degrees);
    }

    public Degree(Degree degrees){
        this.set(degrees);
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return (int)degreeFloat;
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return (long)degreeFloat;
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return degreeFloat;
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return (double)degreeFloat;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Degree compTo) {
        if(compTo.get() > degreeFloat)
            return 1;
        else if(compTo.get() < degreeFloat)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    public Boolean equals(Degree compTo){
        if(degreeFloat == compTo.get()) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public float get(){
        return degreeFloat;
    }

    public void set(Degree setTo){
        this.degreeFloat = setTo.get();
    }

    public void set(float setTo){
        this.degreeFloat = setNormalise(setTo);
    }

    public void set(int setTo){
        this.degreeFloat = setNormalise((float)setTo);
    }

    public void set(double setTo){
        this.degreeFloat = setNormalise((float)setTo);
    }

    public float setNormalise(float setTo){
        float value = setTo;

        while(setTo > 360f)
            setTo -= 360F;

        while(setTo < 0f)
            setTo += 360f;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some comments since you've posted this; you don't need to have overloaded versions for int/float/double; just provide float, since that's what you store anyway (implicit casting will cater for int, and it's worth warning about double). `new Degree(0).equals( new Degree(360) )` will return `false` (actually you have a typo in `setNormalise` which means it will never actually normalise). And your compareTo isn't wrap-around aware (so 361 < 359). Of course, making it wrap-around aware is impossible, but maybe that means you shouldn't allow it?

Comment: I should also point out that your equals function won't always be used (e.g. if put in a Set or Map), because it should take an Object not a Degree (use the @Override annotation on it and you will be warned about this). Also I'd strongly recommend making the class immutable (make degreeFloat final and remove setters), which will make it much safer to use as a type inside other objects (can't be changed externally so doesn't need protective copies made). Sorry to throw such a list at you but these are common pitfalls which I think it's worth being aware of!